# Getting a “Batch : ( was unexpected at this time” error when I attempt to run my Batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm running this batch script which is giving me the error described in the title

```
set /p ActiveMQpath=
ECHO.
if exist %ActiveMQpath%+"\InstallService.bat" (
    ECHO Installer found, starting with ActiveMQ installation. Please wait...
    cd %ActiveMQpath%
    CALL InstallService.bat
    ECHO ActiveMQ Service has been installed
    ECHO Attempting to start service... Please wait
    ECHO.
    timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
    ECHO.
    Set ServiceName=ActiveMQ
    goto StartService
        if %IsServiceRunning% =="TRUE" (
        start iexplore http://localhost:8161/
        ) else ( ECHO Service not running... 
        PAUSE)
    ) else (
    ECHO File not found, please try again
    goto ACTIVEMQ_WRONGPATH)
```

I do not know what i am missing. 
The syntax shows that this should be correct

```
if exist "filename" (
!do job!
) else ( 
!do other job!
)
```

My code does not even go inside the first IF condition

Comment: I don't think batch files support nested IF statements. So instead, you would need to change the first IF to a short check and jump around in the code based on what it does to get out of the IF so your other code can have a new IF. And finally, I spotted a + in your IF statement that I think should not be there.

Comment: @LPChip is absolutely correct. NO nesting. Replace %ActiveMQpath%+"\InstallService.bat" with %ActiveMQpath%\InstallService.bat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems in your batch file.

The first one is that you have nested IF's. Batch files don't support nested IF statements. You'll have to write an If compare and based on its result jump around in your code using goto. That way, you can have your nested IF.

Secondly, I spotted a likely typo that causes the first if to not work even if the nested if was not present. There's a + in it which will see if a path with a + exists. If it doesn't, it will execute the else.

But given that a nested if is a severe error (batch doesn't recognize it) so instead of execution it halts before the script has run.

You want your code to look something like this:

```
    set /p ActiveMQpath=
    ECHO.
    if exist "%ActiveMQpath%\InstallService.bat" goto InstallerExists
    goto InstallerNotFound

:InstallerExists
    ECHO Installer found, starting with ActiveMQ installation. Please wait...
    cd %ActiveMQpath%
    CALL InstallService.bat
    ECHO ActiveMQ Service has been installed
    ECHO Attempting to start service... Please wait

    ECHO.
    timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
    ECHO.

    Set ServiceName=ActiveMQ
    goto StartService

    if "%IsServiceRunning%"=="TRUE" (
        start iexplore http://localhost:8161/
    ) else ( 
        ECHO Service not running... 
        PAUSE
    )
    goto end

:InstallerNotFound
    ECHO File not found, please try again
    goto ACTIVEMQ_WRONGPATH)

:StartService
    ::your code here, missing from snippet...
    goto end

:ACTIVEMQ_WRONGPATH
    ::your code here, missing from snippet...
    goto end

:end
```

Comment: Working now as intended thank you for the tip